# Is it imporant that a cookie should have secure flag set if the website is running on HTTP?

Tags: web-application, cookies

I am working on a website and I want to know if a cookie needs to have a secure flag set or not if the website is running on HTTP. Also, httponly flag is set on cookie but there is no secure flag.

Comment: Why is your site still running on HTTP only?

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation of Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> **Secure** Optional
>   A secure cookie **will only be sent to the server when a request is made using SSL and the HTTPS protocol**. ....
>   Note: Insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the "secure"
>   directive anymore (new in Chrome 52+ and Firefox 52+).

In other words: it makes no sense to set `secure` on plain HTTP at all since a cookie with such a settings would essentially be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The `secure` flag tells the browsers to only send a cookie if the request is being made over HTTPS.   So, if your site only supports HTTP, but you still want the cookie(s) to be sent, then do not set the `secure` flag.